# Blank Page On Right Side After Nav Bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

Sorry if this topic has been discussed too much. I created a navigation menu that will appear on the screen when the vertical scroll 100px and I managed to make it out of the tutorial from the internet. however I found that there is a blank page on the right side of the screen by approximately 5 times the size of the current screen.

Here is the HTML:

```
<header>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li style='margin-left:30px;'><a href='index.php'>Beranda</a></li> 
            <li><a href='#'>Tutorial &#9662;</a> 
                <ul class='sub-menu'> 
                    <li><a href='#'>CSS</a></li> 
                    <li><a href='#'>HTML5</a></li> 
                    <li><a href='#'>Javascript</a></li> 
                </ul> 
            </li> 
            <li><a href='#'>Web Design &#9662;</a>
                <ul class='sub-menu'>
                <li><a href='#'>Blogger Template</a></li> 
                <li><a href='#'>Menu Navigasi</a></li> 
                <li><a href='#'>Responsive Design</a></li> 
                <li><a href='#'>Codding</a></li> 
                </ul> 
            </li> 
            <li><a href='#'>About Us</a></li> 
            <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</header>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
header {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
display: none;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
height: 30px;
background-color: rgba(238,238,238,0.8);
z-index:100;
font-family:'Oswald', Arial, sans serif;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
box-shadow:         0px 3px 5px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.49);
}
header ul, header ul ul.sub-menu {
padding:0;
margin: 0;
}
header ul li, header ul ul.sub-menu li, header ul ul.sub-menu ul.sub-sub-menu li {
list-style-type: none;
display: inline-block;
margin:0; 
padding:0; 
}
header ul li a {
padding:0 5px; 
display: inline-block; 
height: 30px; 
text-align: left; 
line-height: 30px; 
text-decoration: none; 
color:#333;
font-size:20px;
}
header li:hover a { 
color: #eee; 
text-decoration:none; 
background: #888; 
} 
header ul li ul.sub-menu li a {
display: inline-block; 
background: rgba(238,238,238,0.8); 
color: #333; 
height: 30px; 
line-height: 20px;
font-size:14px;
font-weight:300;
min-width: 160px; 
padding: 5px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}
header ul li ul.sub-menu li:hover a { 
color: #eee; 
text-decoration:none; 
background: #888;
}
header ul li ul.sub-menu li ul.sub-sub-menu li a {
display: inline-block; 
background: rgba(238,238,238,0.8); 
color: #333; 
height: 30px; 
line-height: 20px;
font-size:14px;
font-weight:300;
min-width: 160px; padding: 5px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}
header ul li ul.sub-menu li ul.sub-sub-menu li:hover a { 
color: #eee; 
text-decoration:none; 
background: #888;
}
header ul li {
position: relative;
}
header ul li ul.sub-menu {
display:none;
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
left: 0;
width: 100px;
}
header ul li:hover ul.sub-menu {
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight:300;
}
header ul li ul.sub-menu li ul.sub-sub-menu {
display:none;
position: absolute;
top:0;
left: 100%;
width: 100px;
}
header ul li ul.sub-menu li:hover ul.sub-sub-menu {
display: inline-block;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight:300;
}
```

Here is the JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if ( $(this).scrollTop() > 100 && !$('header').hasClass('open') ) {
    $('header').addClass('open');
    $('header').slideDown();
  } else if ( $(this).scrollTop() <= 100 ) {
  $('header').removeClass('open');
  $('header').slideUp();
}
});
```

I want to ask, if there are any errors in the CSS that I made?
Thank you for your help. 
* sorry I was not very good at speaking English

Comment: The markup that you have posted works completely fine. Maybe this is getting caused due to some other setting that you may have missed to post here. Can your try and create a fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though it works [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5w6g1497/). I just added a declaration of body height like this:

```
body {
    height: <any height greater than 100px>;
}
```

I think maybe a bit more info is needed to see what you are talking about. Do you have this page live somewhere? Even a slightly more complete picture of the html that you are working with. I can't see the 'blank area' you are talking about here.